# Mongodb which query condition is not met

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if its possible to check which condition is not met when doing a mongodb query for example.

```
User: {
   name : 'John',
   age : 18
}

User.findOne({
    'name' : 'John',
    'age' : { $gte : 20}
}, function(err,result){
   // here get some kind of error that a 'John' was found but not with that age
})
```

Comment: It's not possible since the result will be undefined should the query not satisfy any of the conditions because it's an implicit AND operation. It's a different case altogether if the query consisted of an OR logic then if one of the conditions in the `$or` operator list matches, you can then compare the result with the query to see where the match came from.